# Correctly attributing github libraries without specific mentioning

Tags: apache-2.0, github, license-notice, attribution

I would to attribue some of the OpenSource libraries that I'm using in my project but I found my self having problems in doing so since it is not written clear (in my opinion).

For example, the following project:

https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http

If I click on the NOTICE.txt file it says inside:

```
Android Async Http Client library
Copyright (c) 2011-2015 James Smith <james@loopj.com>
https://loopj.com

Copyright (c) 2015-2019 Marek Sebera <marek@msebera.cz>
htts://msebera.cz

This product includes software developed by
The Apache Software Foundation (https://www.apache.org/).
```

While if I click on the Wiki tab it says:

```
The Android Asynchronous Http Client is released under the Apache License, Version 2.0.
Read the full license here: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
```

And if so, how do I attribute then? From my knowledge Apache 2.0 attribution should be from the following form:

```
Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]
```

Does the `https://loopj.com` for example should be part of the name of copyright owner?

Another example is:

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-android

When opening the `LICENSE` file, it just shows the `Apache 2.0` license. How can I know the year and name of copyright owner?

Thank you

Comment: You should show the contents of the NOTICE file. Unabridged and unaltered. That's how the authors define their copyright and want to see it shown; that's the purpose of that file

Comment: But it seems like Apache 2.0 format and in the Wiki link it says Apache 2.0 so why cant I for example push them together under Apache 2.0 license with other open sources?

Comment: I think you should be open an issue on github and said to clarify it. Sometimes the open-source developer (like me) miss some important details on license